# Remove multiple fragments in back stack

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments

Suppose we have three fragments hosted in an activity on our back stack

A->B->C

When I click on back press on fragment C I also want to immediately remove B from the back stack.Note that in some cases I might want to go back to B but for the most part I want to clear out C and B together to get to A.How can I achieve this should I call popBackStack() twice or should I have some kind of delegate mechanism to notify B that C has been closed and we don't expect to show B so please clean up.

Answer (score 1):

In fragment A do this..

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.containerMain, new FragmentA()).addToBackStack("BACKSTACK_FRAGMENT_A")
                .commit();
```

and do not use `addToBackStack(..)`
in this case you'll always return to Fragment A when you press back from other Fragments. 
and when are going to specify back press to specific fragment

Add Fragments To BackStack. Before commit() the transaction, use addToBackStack() method i.e

```
 addToBackStack("Some String").commit();
```

and in onBackPressed()

```
@Override 
public void onBackPressed() { 
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(); 
    } else { 
        this.finish(); 
    }
}
```